# NGINX default config from DigitalOcean highlighted as high risk

Tags: nginx

I have the following NGINX config which was created by DigitalOcean's NodeJS image by default. I already modified this config but still the security scan tool, in this case, I used OWASP ZAP, still highlights this as high risk.  The config is as follows:

```
server {

    # SSL configuration
    ...
    root /var/www/mywebsite;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name mywebsite.com; # managed by Certbot


    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires 12h;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;     
    }
    
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

My UI is build from React so I just placed the build artifacts inside `/var/www/mywebsite`.

The highlighted risk is as follows:

```
Cloud Metadata Potentially Exposed
Solution:
Do not trust any user data in NGINX configs. In this case it is probably the use of the $host variable which is set from the 'Host' header and can be controlled by an attacker.
Reference:
https://www.nginx.com/blog/trust-no-one-perils-of-trusting-user-input/
```

It says something about the overly permitted proxy that is causing this but I still cannot figure out which part I need to change.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this config - the Certbot simply redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

Comment: Actually i wanted to fix that high risk highlighted by OWASP ZAP on the NGINX config but not sure what to change to fix that vulnerability.

Comment: You can simply remove that part of the config - Certbot will restore it the next time.

Comment: can you please help point which part of the config to remove?

Comment: The block that says `if ($host = mywebsite.com) { .... } # managed by Certbot`

Comment: The same thing, still highlights as High Risk after commenting those lines.

Comment: Simply remove them from the config and the warning will go away.

Comment: I already removed those lines you mentioned, still the same warning.

Comment: If the word `$host` is not present in your nginX configuration - then the warning is a lie and you should not trust that tool.

Answer (score 0):

The Host header can be manipulated, so a potential attacker could exploit the fact that you are using the $host variable to carry out a variety of attacks. Try changing this part of the configuration:

```
server {
    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

Comment: `if $host = mywebsite.com then use $host..` no problem there (this is generated by Certbot, if it was a problem certbot maintainers would stopped using it)

Comment: Question is about why OWASP ZAP highlights this .conf as a risk. Provided code should mitigate this warning as explained. e.g. source: https://www.nginx.com/blog/trust-no-one-perils-of-trusting-user-input/